# ESP32, How to extract Strings from filtered Json object

Tags: json, filter, esp32

I have a very large Json object where I applied the following filter:

```
StaticJsonDocument<160> filter;
      filter["responses"][0]["textAnnotations"][0]["description"] = true;
      filter["responses"][0]["imagePropertiesAnnotation"]["dominantColors"]["colors"] = true;
```

Then I deserialize the object I got from the online service as below:

```
// Deserialize the document
StaticJsonDocument<1000> doc;
deserializeJson(doc, jSonResponse, DeserializationOption::Filter(filter));
```

To check the resulting jSon I print it to the console as below:

```
// Print the result
serializeJsonPretty(doc, Serial);
```

And get the following printout:

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "textAnnotations": [
        {
          "description": "FIRT\nNG-FIRT LABORATORY\nPZE 5068\n"
        },
        {
          "description": "FIRT"
        },
        {
          "description": "NG-FIRT"
        },
        {
          "description": "LABORATORY"
        },
        {
          "description": "PZE"
        },
        {
          "description": "5068"
        }
      ],
      "imagePropertiesAnnotation": {
        "dominantColors": {
          "colors": [
            {
              "color": {
                "red": 158,
                "green": 23,
                "blue": 24
              },
              "score": 0.158183,
              "pixelFraction": 0.031844
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I use a service at https://codebeautify.org/json-decode-online to identify the variables position into the resulting json above and extract and print as below:

```
const char* cObject = doc["responses"][0]["textAnnotations"][0]["description"];
const char* cRed   = doc["responses"]["imagePropertiesAnnotation"]["dominantColors"]["colors"][0]["color"]["red"];
const char* cGreen = doc["responses"]["imagePropertiesAnnotation"]["dominantColors"]["colors"][0]["color"]["green"];
const char* cBlue  = doc["responses"]["imagePropertiesAnnotation"]["dominantColors"]["colors"][0]["color"]["blue"];

Serial.print("cObject: ");
Serial.println(cObject);
Serial.print("cRed: ");
Serial.println(cRed);
Serial.print("cGreen: ");
Serial.println(cGreen);
Serial.print("cBlue: ");
Serial.println(cBlue);
```

And the printout comes as below:

```
cObject: FIRT
    NG-FIRT LABORATORY
    PZE 5068
cRed: 
cGreen: 
cBlue:
```

Only cObject is printed and no matter what I do I cannot get the colors to be displayed.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: doc["responses"] **[0]** ["imagePropertiesAnnotation"].......

Comment: Hi Maxin, your clue was instrumental to solving the problem. I also had to change the variable type from (const char*) to (int) for the color values. Thanks